# Android Activity [opening the already running instance]

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I am trying to develop an Android application in which I want to reopen the already running instance of the application rather than creating a new one.

I tried using `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and `singleInstance` but nothing is working. Whenever I click on the launcher icon it creates a new activity [Thread] as I observed using the logcat.

[image]

Every time I launch the application another thread starts as we can see using hte Thread ID in the log.

Comment: I have shared the log. Please check.

Comment: add sysout in onCreate and share log with info mode again